# How to auth with axios npm package

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, axios

In the past i used some php code to query an api like this

```
$str = file_get_contents('https://bla:bla@bla.com/rest/api/content/2950446?expand=body.storage');
$jsonObj = json_decode($str, true);
```

Now i want to built an alexa skill using nodejs

i tested this

```
var session_url = 'https://bla.com/rest/api/content/2950446';


const fetchQuotes = async () => {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.post(session_url, {}, {
            auth: {
                username: 'bla',
                password: 'bla'
            }});
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('cannot fetch quotes', error);
    }
};
```

from my understanding this should do the same. is that the case? The URL is called but I get an auth error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're putting your `data` in the `options` field when you call `axios.post`. Your **data needs to be the 2nd argument** of `axios.post` not the 3rd.

When doing `axios.post(url, {}, { somethingHere }` your `data` is equal to `{}` (empty object). You should do this instead `axios.post(url, { somethingHere }, { config }` and the `config` part is optional.

## Correct argument order

```
const fetchQuotes = async () => {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.post(session_url, {
            auth: {
                username: 'bla',
                password: 'bla'
            }});
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('cannot fetch quotes', error);
    }
};
```

Comment: i tested this. sadly still the same

Comment: what's the error you have? put it as an edit into the question